How to reduce main.ts bundle size In Angular 17 with SSR
Project Is built In Angular 17 with SSR.
We are trying to optimzed main.js bundle size with multiple ways/ideas but it's reflect with good result on Google Page Speed.
Following are the core files.
package.json
{
  "name": "happy-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:cs-production": "ng build --aot --vendor-chunk --build-optimizer --common-chunk --configuration=production && copy-files-from-to --config productionFilesReplacement.json && ng run happy-frontend:server:production --bundle-dependencies true",
    "build:cs-staging": "ng build --aot --vendor-chunk --build-optimizer --optimization --common-chunk --configuration=staging && copy-files-from-to --config stagingFilesReplacement.json && ng run happy-frontend:server:staging",
    "build-production": "npm run build:cs-production",
    "build-staging": "npm run build:cs-staging",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --configuration production && ng run happy-frontend:server:production",
    "stage:ssr": "ng build --configuration staging && ng run happy-frontend:server:production",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --aot --vendor-chunk --build-optimizer --common-chunk --configuration production && ng run happy-frontend:server:production --bundle-dependencies true",
    "server": "node local.js",
    "serve:prerender": "node static.js",
    "build:prerender": "npm run build:cs-production && node dist/prerender.js",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run happy-frontend:serve-ssr",
    "prerender": "ng run happy-frontend:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.2",
    "@builder.io/partytown": "^0.9.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.14.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^11.0.1",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^14.0.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "copy-files-from-to": "^3.2.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "lottie-web": "^5.7.13",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^9.1.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^17.1.0",
    "ngx-currency": "^17.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^13.5.3",
    "ngx-mask": "^17.0.7",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^16.0.0",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^11.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.3"
  }
}


angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "happy-frontend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/redirect301.txt",
              "src/blog-sitemap.xml",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/1ef6c54ce143a13ef153fa055a7fdedc.txt",
              "src/google81c976b0dacf5007.html",
              "src/file",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale",
                "output": "/assets/locale/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/azure-storage.blob.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lottie-web",
              "lodash",
              "rxjs",
              "angular-instantsearch",
              "hogan.js",
              "rxjs-compat",
              "sweetalert2",
              "crypto-js",
              "chart.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.prod.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "index": {
                "input": "src/index.stag.html",
                "output": "index.html"
              },
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stag.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": {
                  "minify": true,
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": true
              },
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "6mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "happy-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "happy-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "happy-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stag.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "happy-frontend:build",
            "serverTarget": "happy-frontend:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "happy-frontend:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "happy-frontend:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "stage-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "happy-frontend:build",
            "serverTarget": "happy-frontend:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "happy-frontend:build:staging",
              "serverTarget": "happy-frontend:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "happy-frontend:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "happy-frontend:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "happy-frontend-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "happy-frontend:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "happy-frontend:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './routes/routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

app.config.server.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './routes/routes';
import { provideClientHydration, withHttpTransferCacheOptions } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { provideNgxMask } from 'ngx-mask';
import { provideToastr } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ProgressInterceptor, BasicAuthInterceptor } from './shared/helpers';
import { StorageService } from './shared/service';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration(withHttpTransferCacheOptions({
        includePostRequests: true
    })), provideNgxMask(), {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: ProgressInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }, {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }, provideAnimations(),
        CookieService, StorageService, provideToastr({ positionClass: 'toast-top-right' }),
    importProvidersFrom(ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule),]
};

app.server.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerModule
  ],
})
export class AppServerModule { }

main.ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import './icons';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppComponent } from '@app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from '@app/app.config.server';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));

main.server.ts
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";

import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from "@app/app.component";
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config.server';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig);

export default bootstrap;

export { AppServerModule } from "./app/app.server.module";

export { renderModule } from "@angular/platform-server";

Reduce main.js bundle size

We have updates configuration as per Angular 17 and site loading In milliseconds.
